# Render modals in rails using stimulus js

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have read a lot of articles online on rendering modals, but most of them use bootstrap, or most of the solutions are old. Currently, I am showing modals like,

```rb
# projects_controller

def new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

and in `new.js.erb`

```js
const portal = document.getElementById('modal-portal')
portal.innerHTML = "<%=j render 'form' %>"
```

and the modal gets rendered on the `modal-portal` as expected.

I want to know if there are modern solutions to this, that is without using the `.js.erb` template, and is there a way to do it with `stimulus js`.